# stop video show by opencv when no face detected

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

How can i control the video display when the face is not in front of the camera?
My project is to play the movie as long as there's a front-facing camera
But my problem is that the video is showing up when it finishes

```
for i, face in enumerate(faces):
    self.draw_label(frame, (face[0], face[1]), label)
    if name='john' :

       cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Documents/face/123.mp4')
       while faces is not None:
             ret, frameo = cap.read()
             gray = cv2.cvtColor(frameo,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
             cv2.imshow('framey',frameo)
             cv2.imshow('grayF',gray)
             if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
       cap.release()
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    elif name='matin':
         cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Documents/face/mat.mp4')

         ret, frameo = cap.read()
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(frameo,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         cv2.imshow('framey',frameo)
         cv2.imshow('grayF',gray)
         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It can not be answered without knowing previous part of the code (how you obtain "faces" variable).

Comment: faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=10,minSize=(self.face_size, self.face_size)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, John!. Please click edit and paste your comment (properly formatted) into the question and delete your comment. It's important to provide as much detail as you can in the main question. People don't always see the comments.